# PrestaShopDatabaseException - Unknown column 'cf.show_invoice' in 'field list'

Tags: prestashop-1.7

After migrating a prestashop 1.7 from one server to another, quite everything works fine.

Ordering / paying is ok

Order displays for the customer and the shop-owner.

But when clicking on the order to view the details, there is a big failure with messages =

SELECT fd.*, cfl.*, cf.type, cf.show_invoice FROM is_velsof_supercheckout_fields_data fd JOIN is_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields_lang cfl ON fd.id_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields = cfl.id_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields JOIN is_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields cf ON cf.id_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields = cfl.id_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields WHERE id_order = "3059" AND cfl.id_lang = "1"

at line 769 in file classes/db/Db.php

https://snipboard.io/tOELSc.jpg

Does anyone have a clue about this please ?

PS : the 6 mysql tables used by supercheckout are the same between old server and new server

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear,
a module query is looking for a field that is not present in the DB.

Check in your DB that the table "is_velsof_supercheckout_custom_fields" contains the field "show_invoice".

If the module version on the "new" server is different from the one on the old server, make sure the module upgrade procedure has been triggered, maybe some new field had been added in a recent version.